# Ordering rows with a `timestamptz` by "soonest" in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I have a table of events, each row containing a nullable `timestamptz` column. Some values are in the past, others in the future.

What I want is a query that will return a list of events ordered by the "soonest" event, with events in the past sorted to the bottom of the list.

So for example, if the table has the following values:

```
A  2021-06-25T00:00:00-05:00
B  2021-06-28T00:00:00-05:00
C  2021-06-30T00:00:00-05:00
D  2022-08-01T00:00:00-05:00
E  2021-07-01T00:00:00-05:00
```

And a `NOW()` time of `2021-06-29T00:00:00-05:00`,

I want the list ordered as:

```
C  2021-06-30T00:00:00-05:00
E  2021-07-01T00:00:00-05:00
D  2022-08-01T00:00:00-05:00
B  2021-06-28T00:00:00-05:00
A  2021-06-25T00:00:00-05:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
   /* primo, future values are always sorted first */
   colname <= current_timestamp,
   /* secundo, values closer to now are sorted first */
   abs(EXTRACT(epoch FROM colname - current_timestamp))
```

This relies on the fact that `FALSE < TRUE`.

Comment: Okay, I am going to use this! It works a heck of a lot better than my awful query, and doesn't rely on any arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to first sort them by future or past, and then sort by which date is the closest to the current date.

You can think of the first ordering expression as putting the rows into groups. Then the second ordering expression will order the rows within each group. (Not to be confused with actual groups using GROUP BY.)

You can also think of your second ordering expression as the absolute value of the difference between that date and the current date.

I've created a temporary table to illustrate:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE timestamps (
    id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    value timestamptz
) 
ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO timestamps
    (value)
VALUES
    (NOW() + INTERVAL '1 week'),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 week'),
    (NOW() + INTERVAL '2 weeks'),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 weeks'),
    (NOw() + INTERVAL '3 weeks'),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL '3 weeks');

SELECT
    id, value
FROM timestamps
ORDER BY
  NOW() < value DESC,
  GREATEST(
    value - NOW(),
    NOW() - value
  );

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've gone ahead and done this:

```
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN (event.event_date < NOW()) THEN (event.event_date + make_interval(50) - NOW())
             ELSE event.event_date - NOW() END ASC
```

I don't love it. But it approximates the desired behavior anyway, in that future events are ordered by soonest, and past events are at the end. `make_interval(50)` adds 50 years to events in the past. It's an arbitrary number but it works until something better comes along.